# presentViewController doesn't do anything

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a method called:

```
- (NSDictionary *)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
```

As you probably guessed, it starts when i get a request back from a web server.

My issue is that the next command runs, but doesn't do anything…

```
[self presentViewController:loadingPageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I feel like I forgot to init something but I can't anything wrong.

Comment: Did you init `loadingPageVC`? Show that code.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add this part. loadingPageVC = [[LoadingPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingPage" bundle:nil];

Comment: Can you `NSLog` the loadingPageVC before you present it?

Comment: Post your declaration of loadingPageVC. Is it strong referenced? Do you use ARC?

Comment: 2013-01-07 22:15:10.142 Locator[3329:907] <LoadingPage: 0x1cda0d30>

Comment: I do use ARC and it is not declared as strong. I forgot the name of the definition i gave it…… Here it is:  @implementation WSRequestHandler
{
    RequestHandler *requestHandler;
    LoadingPage *loadingPageVC;
}

Comment: I tried declaring it as strong… didn't help

Comment: Does it matter if it is in a "switch" code?

Comment: I can't really tell without seeing that part, but try putting every case in a separate block (as recommended by apple in one of the ARC videos): `case 1: { code here; break;} ...`. Strong should be default bts, no need to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self presentViewController:loadingPageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, but can you explain me why this is the case? I understand that this queues the call and executes it a moment later; but this is normally executed in the main thread already, so what's the difference?